# Is this schematic for a DWM3000 Breakout PCB designed correctly?

Tags: schematics, altium, breakout

Is my schematic for a DWM3000 breakout PCB (made in Altium) designed correctly? I have it connected to a TSM 2.54mm connector. I only intend to use the functions I have connected to the TSM. Any mistakes/violations or potential improvements to make to the design?

[image]

Comment: I see no serious flaws. My criticism mainly concerns the poor readability (for the low complexity of this circuit). The lines are all over the place. For discrete components I would expect component attributes instead of part numbers (nobody wants to search for the part numbers when it comes to simple discrete components). I only checked a single resistor and saw it was a 0402 SMT part. I wouldn't advice using 0402 parts, unless absolutely necessary. They're really difficult to solder by hand. What I'm missing is a 100Ω resistor on the Q1 gate.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things my eyes have caught:

- Place a resistor across the gate and the source of the Q1 MOSFET to ensure a normally-off state. 10k ~ 100k would do. Without that resistor the Q1 may falsely turn on in case of a floating gate input. Also, a gate stopper resistor (series) will help to reduce the peak drive currents drawn from the controller-side. This depends on the drive strength but 100 ohms should be okay for most of the applications. I also assume that external reset will not be a repetitive action so the gate stopper resistor may further be increased if necessary.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8h6ng.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- You may want to define a default state for the WAKEUP pin e.g. placing a pull-down resistor.
- There's a special state for GPIO8 that you may want to take a look at. Check the datasheet for details.
- I see that the drive strength for GPIO's are given as 0.8 mA. You may want to consider driving LEDs via transistors instead of direct drive.
- I personally don't find it convenient to use SPI as a board to board communication but let's ignore this for now. I'd put series resistors on SPI lines in case I need non-zero resistors there (starting with zero ohms, of course).